# Selenium ide - How do I copy and paste a randomly generated name

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Would like to know if its possible to copy a randomly generated username and paste into a login field. Most of the StoreValue commands don't apply here as the name is generated new each time, so i need to find a script that would capture/store an unknown value if possible.

Test scenario is like this

Account is registered and a random username and specified password is generated on the web page. The format of the username shows up as:

Registration complete!
Username: Xxxxxxxxxx
Password: Xxxxxxxxxx

I need to now ask Selenium to read that username, copy it and paste it to a login field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Store the required text in variable like I stored in variable s and Try to access same variable using command ${s}

|Command | Target | Value |

|storeText | //ul/li | s |

|echo |${s}|

Also you can get more help from http://voices.yahoo.com/selenium-ide-commands-functions-data-verification-6633440.html?cat=15